# What does it mean that two languages are genetically unrelated?

Tags: history, linguistics, philology

I would like to know what does it mean that two languages are genetically unrelated?

I have seen answer in this topic [Genetic Relatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234/genetic-relatives) what does it mean that languages are genetically realted but how would look the definition of unrelated languages and are there any examples of those?

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking here exactly. You’ve read nohat’s answer that explains what it means that two languages are genetically related—if they’re not genetically related, that just means anything that doesn’t fit nohat’s description. It’s the same as with human families: you’re closely related to your siblings and parents; more distantly related to your great-grandmother’s husband’s grandson’s wife (but still related); and not at all related (that you know of) to that random person you pass in the street.

Comment: Oh, since you asked for definition: unrelated languages are languages where it cannot be reasonably shown that they once belonged to a single language. For example, English and Chinese, or Swedish and Finnish.

Comment: See this image for an idea of what is meant by related languages and levels of relatedness: http://www.public.iastate.edu/~cfford/Indoeuropean%20language%20family%20tree.jpg Keep in mind that there are many other trees; this one includes only one "family" of languages. I don't personally know enough to say if all the languages on one tree are "genetically" related, or if this only applies to languages on the same branch.

Answer (score 2):

In the modern globalised world all languages are in some sense related. E.g.Japanese for shirt is 'waishatsu', which simply derives from 'white shirt'. 'Bread', a food introduced by westerners is 'pan' which may well derive from French.  In Malaysia, when a shop is closed, there will be a sign saying 'tutup', which came from the English 'shut up'. But these kinds of connections will not be considered 'genetic'.

Genetic relatives will be German and Dutch, Italian and Romanian etc. languages which have common roots. English has at least two kinds of genetic relative, the W German group, and French.